# Skip type check on unused parameters

Tags: typescript, unused-variables

When I compile my typescript project, I'm using the `noImplicitAny` option so that I won't forget to specify the types on my variables and arguments.

However sometimes you have arguments that you don't use. For example:

```
jQuery.ajaxTransport("+*", function (options: JQueryAjaxSettings) {
  return {
    abort: function (_, callback: JQueryCallback) {
```

I am not interested in the first argument of the abort function, so I ignore it by naming it _.

Is that the proper way to do that in TypeScript? I couldn't find it in the guide. I suspect that it isn't the proper way, because I can only name one argument _.

Typescript raises the following error:

> error TS7006: Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.

I could just type `_:any` but that seems a bit overkill for an argument that I don't use.

Comment: there's no such thing as a default parameter name. if you enabled noImplicitAny you must specify the type for everything.

Comment: I am basically looking for the equivalent of Swift's ignored parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338045/what-is-the-usecase-for-ignored-parameters-in-swift

Comment: there's no such thing in JS or typescript. :)

Comment: @toskv that's unfortunate, but thank you. If you add it as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14154

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I was having the same problem.
Using say express and routing you would often only want the res parameter.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) { res.end('Bye.'); });
```

Your idea of using _ works here, but I've also found doing this works too.

```
function (_1, _2, _3, onlyThis) { console.log(onlyThis); }
```

This seems better, as only doing '_' I think might make using lodash/underscore a bit confusing, and it also makes it obvious it's the 4th parameter your interested in.

> Update: It's been a long time since I posted this answer, and in the
> comments I'm getting a few miss conceptions.  So though I would
> clarify.

Using the underscore trick is still very useful in Typescript.  Like I mentioned in my original answer say if you was using express and did `app.get('/', (req, res) => {` you will get a warning `'req' is declared but its value is never read`, but if you do -> `app.get('/', (_req, res) => {` the warning will go away.  You should not get the `error TS7006: Parameter 'req' implicitly has an 'any' type.` error anyway, as `@types/express` should be implicitly typing this param anyway.

> Update 2,.  Please note the second answer here using `{}` for parameters, might look cool, but it's considerable slower, so personally I would be careful using inside tight loops.

Comment: Would the numbered parameters not also have an implied `any` type? That was the problem that the OP was trying to resolve.

Comment: @MichaelLPerry   It was to get around this problem ->  `because I can only name one argument _.`  The underscore trick also works for Linters too.  Also at the time not sure how Typescript handled this,  currently checking on an unused parameter seems a bit odd anyway, so I'd say if Typescript is still treating underscore params as unused, this warning should not appear.  You would now need to do `_1:any, _2:any`..

Comment: Why use numbers instead of something like `_req`? And yes, this doesn't answer the OP's question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong in using `_req`,  never said there was.  In fact it's what I tend to do now, but my original answer was done Sept 2016.  Not sure what Typescript & Linters were doing then, and my Javascript skills were very new then too.. :)

Comment: I dont understand why this got the votes: `Parameter '_' implicitly has an 'any' type.`  is still a very valid error

Comment: This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @user2398029  It still works for me, I've updated my answer to try an clarify it's usage.

Answer (score 35):

I may be late, but I got stuck with the other solutions and this one work all the time for me:

```
function ({}={}, {}={}, {}={}, onlyThis) { console.log(onlyThis); }
```

## comparison

When using the `_0`, `_1`, ... solution, I faced difficulties with scooped function like:

```
function parent(_0, _1, _2) {
  function child(_0, _1, _2) {
    // TypeScript crying about shadowed variables
  }
}
```

but with the empty object it work well:

```
function parent({}, {}, {}) {
  function child({}, {}, {}) {
    // :-)
  }
}
```

Even if the parameters are typed like:

```
function parent({}: number, {}: string, {}: any) {
  function child({}: number, {}: string, {}: any) {
    // :-) x2
  }
}
```

EDIT:

And as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197927/standard-conventions-for-indicating-a-function-argument-is-unused-in-javascript#comment78430661_37614082), setting a default value avoid error throwing if the given parameter is `undefined` or `null`.

```
function parent({}={}, {}={}, {}={}) {
  function child({}={}, {}={}, {}={}) {
    // :-)
  }
}
```

Comment: According to the linked answer this only avoids throwing when passing `undefined` not when passing `null`.

Comment: So this is using [object destructuring](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#destructuring) for each parameter. For me, I needed to specify the third parameter, so I did something like `({}, e: SomeType) => {/* use e here… */}`

Comment: @hraban  If performance is an issue, do bear in mind this is much slower,.  So in tight loops I would avoid.

Comment: this might work but is UGLY ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely unholy but you can use this:

```
function fn(...[,,,param]){
  console.log(param)
}
fn(2,3,4,5) //prints(5)
```