# How to reference multiple unnamed parameters inside a swift function

Tags: swift, function, parameters

I know this is not a good thing to do, but I'm extremely curious how this would work.

I can create a function like this and call it, but I don't see how to reference the parameters

```
func printMultipleOf_v2(_ : Int, _ : Int) {
   //how to reference parameters?  
}
printMultipleOf_v2(2, 4)
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess I could.  Its getting down votes, so I thought I would emphasize its actually a good technique based on your answer.

Comment: Just upvote/accept his answer if you want. Or add some affirmative comment under his answer if you think it worthy to clarify why it's a good answer. Or [post your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want to add something substantive.

Comment: @RichHoffman You can accept my answer if it works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters are called "ignored parameters", which are not meant to be referenced. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24338946/8560567) for why ignored parameters are used.

From https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-4-functions-3cce9d9bba4, "An ignored parameter frees us of having to come up with a name for a parameter we don’t use, like when we override a method and don’t use a given parameter, or implement a closure and don’t use a given parameter. "

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use these parameters, you would simply specify an argument label of `_`, but then specify an actual parameter name:

```
func printMultiple(_ x: Int, _ y: Int) {
    // now use x and y
}
```

As a result, while you can still reference `x` and `y` (or whatever) inside the function, the calling point doesn't need any labels:

```
printMultiple(2, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting and challenging!
But, looking at Swift 4 syntax (The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4)), that should not be authorized:

```
parameter → external-parameter-nameoptlocal-parameter-nametype-annotation
parameter → external-parameter-nameoptlocal-parameter-nametype-annotation...
external-parameter-name → identifier
local-parameter-name → identifier
```

where identifier must have an identifier_head defined here

```
identifier → identifier-headidentifier-charactersopt
identifier → `identifier-headidentifier-charactersopt`
identifier → implicit-parameter-name
identifier-list → identifier  identifier,identifier-list
identifier-head → Upper- or lowercase letter A through Z
identifier-head → _
identifier-head → U+00A8, U+00AA, U+00AD, U+00AF, U+00B2–U+00B5, or U+00B7–U+00BA
identifier-head → U+00BC–U+00BE, U+00C0–U+00D6, U+00D8–U+00F6, or U+00F8–U+00FF
identifier-head → U+0100–U+02FF, U+0370–U+167F, U+1681–U+180D, or U+180F–U+1DBF
identifier-head → U+1E00–U+1FFF
```

So, in this case, you simply cannot refer to the parameters: the _ is not for external name, but for internal name.

Comment: Yes, it lets you compile.  I put that code in a playground and it compiled.  However, looking at xcoder's answer it makes a ton of sense why that is now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you can't. By declaring your parameters like that, you are expressly telling the compiler to ignore them. If you need to refer to them, give them an internal name:

```
func printMultipleOf_v2(_ lhs: Int, _ rhs: Int) {
    //how to reference parameters?
    print(lhs, rhs)
}
```

So this is a case of "Don't do that."